# Why was this question migrated over to webmasters.se?

Tags: discussion, moderation

I just saw this question on the homepage of stackexchange: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/25360/student-homepage-template-for-google-sites

As far as I can tell, the question is asking for someone to tell them how to get a certain theme on google sites. That question should be on webapps.se, but it was migrated over to webmasters.se *from webapps.se*. What's going on?

Comment: Inquiring at [WebApps chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7/webapps) now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Followed up with phwd at WebApps to revert migration - apparently Google Sites is blurring the line between "webmaster" and "end user" for their purposes, will address any future migrations on a case-by-case basis (I can see where some Google Sites users' questions would be fit here, but questions about *how to use* Google Sites don't belong here so far as I can see).

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little concerned that these blurred lines are preventing users from getting answers to questions, even if some of the questions are of low quality.

Comment: I agree, it [isn't what I'd call ideal](http://meta.webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/382/1064), but, for the time being, low quality questions shouldn't be a top priority (consider that low quality questions most often represent failure to read the manual and have been answered... in the manual)

Comment: @danlefree You make a fair point, although a good number of users don't appear to have english as a first language.